# Italian equivalent of the idiomatic expression "It's all very well doing ..., but ..."

Tags: word-usage, meaning

> Fare qualcosa **è una gran bella cosa, certo, ma** non dovremmo fare ... ?

I think I just heard the phrase above in conversation, and given its similar construction to the similar expressions in other languages,  I'm assuming it means:

> **Va bene** fare qualcosa, ma non dovremmo fare ... ?

And I'm assuming it is an equivalent of:

> It's **all very well** doing A, but shouldn't we do B first?
>
> {or}: It's **all well and good/dandy** to do ..., but ...

---

There must be several different ways to convey this idea in Italian, but what about the nuances between them?

For instance, in English you can also say "X is **nice and all**, but ...". In this specific construction, however, the subject X tends to be a single word or a relatively short, few word-long phrase. In case a subject is rather long, on the other hand, you switch to the construction "It's **all very well** doing A, but ...", so that you can effectively contain a longer subject in the part "doing A".

I wonder if the construction "X è una gran bella cosa, certo, ma ..." has similar traits to  the construction  "X is nice and all, but ..." in this very respect?

Comment: ***Collins Dictionary*** gives the following translation: *It is all very well, but*: ***va benissimo, ma***..., ***d'accordo, ma***... 
 https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english-italian/that-s-all-very-well-but-

Comment: Yes, these idiomatic expressions are generally used   to complain about something that isn't bad, but doesn’t  match your tastes or interests. So you may say  "It's nice and all,  but...", “D’accordo, ma”.